# Django Error on Form instead of raising a ValidationError

Tags: django, django-forms

I was wondering how I could show an error on the form instead of raising a validation error page. I mean when on the form itself the errorlist is generated, I will attach a screen shot of a different form because my explanation isn't the best haha.

[image: example]

Right now in my view I raise a ValidationError instead of the form just adding the error itself. How can I go about adding the form error instead of raising an actual validation error? I would like the normal behavior of errorlist appearing on my form. Any help is greatly appreciated!

my view is as follows:

```
class EditProfileInformationView(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UserEditForm(initial={
            'first_name': self.request.user.first_name,
            'last_name': self.request.user.last_name,
            'email': self.request.user.email
        })
        context = {
            'form':form
        }
        return render(request, 'accounts/update.html', context)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = UserEditForm(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)
        context = {
            'form': form
        }
        if form.is_valid():
            initial_email = self.request.user.email
            form.save(commit=False)
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            if User.objects.filter(email=email).exists() and email != initial_email:
                raise ValidationError('This email already exists')
            else:
                form.save()
                messages.success(request,'Profile Successfully Updated')
                return redirect('/')
        else:
            return render(request, 'accounts/update.html', context)
```

Comment: do you want display error list on top of the form ? instead of display like validation?

Comment: You can not raise a `ValidationError` in the `post` method. You should implement that in the form, since Django's forms will wrap a try-except over this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you raise a error in the `get`/`post` view functions, then this means the server will return a server error: in case there is an error, your view should still return a HTTP response, perhaps one with a status code in the 400-499 range (client error), but not raise an exception.

In your `UserEditForm`, you thus should implement this uniqness filter with:

```
class UserEditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    # …
    
    def clean_email(self):
        email = self.cleaned_data['email']
        qs = User.objects.exclude(pk=self.object.pk).filter(email=email)
        if qs.exists():
             raise ValidationError('This email already exists')
        return email
```

Normally a view should not perform (extensive) validation, it is up to the form to ensure that the data is valid and cleaned.

Comment: Ahh okay thank you for the information, I wasn't sure if my original way was best practice or not!

Comment: hi, thank you willem, i have used this, everything ok but the html input not cleaned, i mean it has value. how can i remove the value in html form with django?